# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'target_names'- scikit

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a logistic regression model. After reading the data set . I am getting

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b1fbf288405a> in <module>()
     21 df.head(10)  #This should print 10 rows
     22 
---> 23 df.target_names
     24 df.feature_names
     25 

C:\Users\HP\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   3612             if name in self._info_axis:
   3613                 return self[name]
-> 3614             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   3615 
   3616     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'target_names'
```

This is what I have done

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn import preprocessing

# create header for dataset
header = ['age','bp','sg','al','su','rbc','pc','pcc',
    'ba','bgr','bu','sc','sod','pot','hemo','pcv',
    'wbcc','rbcc','htn','dm','cad','appet','pe','ane',
    'classification']
# read the dataset
df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\HP\Documents\machine learning project\Chronic_Kidney_Disease\chronic_kidney_disease_full.arff",
        header=None,
        names=header
       )
# dataset has '?' in it, convert these into NaN
df = df.replace('?', np.nan)
# drop the NaN
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how="any")
df.head(10)  #This should print 10 rows

df.target_names
df.feature_names
```

Can any one tell me why I am getting this error

Comment: You don't have attributes called target_names or feature_names. If you share a few sample rows of the Data Set and explain what you mean by  target_names and feature_names (Is this the header or values), it will be easier to answer the question you have.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to define feature_names and target_names, as they are not native pandas attributes.  If you wanted df.feature_names and df.target_names to return a select group of columns instead, you will need to create a multiindex and set df.columns equal to that.  A multiindex allows you to create multiple-row-headers or indices.  This is described here and can be applied to either rows or columns.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html